# MP3 to midi converting by python (TypeError: Failed to load plugin: mtg-melodia:melodia)

Tags: python, audio, mp3, midi

I am trying to write some codes to convert MP3 files to midi in the main colab page.

so i remember that creating midi file form mp3 is a big project, and I probably have trouble importing a personal song or audio file into this project. (Audio format to MIDI, in some places is done with artificial intelligence (such as [PolyphonicPianoTranscription](https://colab.research.google.com/github/BShakhovsky/PolyphonicPianoTranscription/blob/master/4%20Piano%20Audio%20to%20Midi.ipynb#scrollTo=FkHOJXYbyQdk)), (list of [AudiotoMIDI conversion projects](https://gist.github.com/natowi/d26c7e97443ec97e8032fb7e7596f0b0)).

So i have tried to convert the MP3 to WAV by this function:

```
def MP3_to_WAV(MP3_file):
   from pydub import AudioSegment
   sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(MP3_file)
   filename = os.path.basename(MP3_file)
   wav_file_name=output_path+filename.split('.')[0]+'.wav'
   sound.export(wav_file_name, format="wav")
   return wav_file_name
```

and the tried to convert The WAV to MIDI by [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/983/how-to-extract-the-melody-from-an-audio-file-and-export-it-to-midi-generate-quantized-midi-using-python-in-ubuntu-18-04) instruction and this function:

```
def wav_to_midi(wav_f_n):
   filename2 = os.path.basename(wav_f_n)
   midi_file_name=output_path+filename2.split('.')[0]+'.midi'
   run_comand("python /content/audio_to_midi_melodia/audio_to_midi_melodia.py "+wav_file+' '+ midi_file_name+" 120")
   return midi_file_name
```

but in the **WAV to Midi** Block codes of my colab page ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/So-AI-love/musicautobot/blob/master/notebooks/music_transformer/Generate_colab_upload.ipynb#scrollTo=SpHgpnmH-5fR)),i get this error:

```
Vamp::HostExt::PluginLoader: No library found in Vamp path for plugin "mtg-melodia:melodia"
Loading audio...
Extracting melody f0 with MELODIA...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/audio_to_midi_melodia/audio_to_midi_melodia.py", line 225, in <module>
    savejams=args.jams)
  File "/content/audio_to_midi_melodia/audio_to_midi_melodia.py", line 174, in audio_to_midi_melodia
    parameters={"voicing": 0.2})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/vamp/collect.py", line 166, in collect
    plugin, step_size, block_size = vamp.load.load_and_configure(data, sample_rate, plugin_key, parameters, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/vamp/load.py", line 83, in load_and_configure
    vampyhost.ADAPT_CHANNEL_COUNT)
TypeError: Failed to load plugin: mtg-melodia:melodia
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-c99e6fb96073> in <module>()
     84     print('\n'+files+'\n')
     85     wav_file=MP3_to_WAV(files)
---> 86     midi_file=wav_to_midi(wav_file)
     87 
     88 

2 frames
<ipython-input-35-c99e6fb96073> in execute(command)
     55         return output
     56     else:
---> 57         raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)
     58 
     59 

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I guess it must happened because of the python version mismatching, but is asked here.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root problem is `Vamp::HostExt::PluginLoader: No library found in Vamp path for plugin "mtg-melodia:melodia"`.

So either mtg-melodia:melodia's path needs to be added to Vamp path, or mtg-melodia:melodia needs to be installed and configured.

It looks like you are using the instructions from the following url to set up mtg-melodia.  Could you recheck there for mtg-melodia install and configure details, there may have been a step you missed.
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/983/how-to-extract-the-melody-from-an-audio-file-and-export-it-to-midi-generate-quantized-midi-using-python-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

To install a plugin set, copy the plugin's library file and any supplied category or RDF files into your system or personal Vamp plugin location.

The plugin file extension and the location to copy into depend on which operating system you are using:

**Your operating system****File extension for plugins****Where to put the plugin files****macOS**`.dylib`On a Mac:

- Put plugins for all users to use in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Vamp`
- Put plugins for only the current user in `$HOME/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Vamp`
- The `Library` folders are hidden by default; see [here](http://osxdaily.com/2016/12/12/show-user-library-folder-macos-sierra/) for details of how to show them

**64-bit Windows**`.dll`When using a 64-bit version of Windows:

- Put 32-bit plugins in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vamp Plugins`
- Put 64-bit plugins in `C:\Program Files\Vamp Plugins`
- Both 32-bit and 64-bit plugins can be used, as long as you put them in the right places as above
- If a plugin package is not described as 64-bit, then it is a 32-bit plugin. Some older plugins were only published in 32-bit form.

**32-bit Windows**`.dll`When using a 32-bit version of Windows:

- Put 32-bit plugins in `C:\Program Files\Vamp Plugins`
- You cannot use 64-bit plugins at all on 32-bit Windows
- If a plugin package is not described as 64-bit, then it is a 32-bit plugin. Some older plugins were only published in 32-bit form.

**Linux, other Unix**`.so`On Linux, BSD systems, etc:

- Put plugins for all users to use in `/usr/local/lib/vamp`
- Put plugins for only the current user in `$HOME/vamp`
- Only plugins with the correct architecture can be used (32-bit plugins on 32-bit systems, and 64-bit on 64-bit).

You can alternatively set the `VAMP_PATH` environment variable to override the search path for for Vamp plugins. `VAMP_PATH` should contain a semicolon-separated (on Windows) or colon-separated (macOS, Linux) list of directory locations. If it is set, it will completely override the standard locations listed above. (N.B. When using 32-bit plugins on 64-bit Windows, some hosts will check for the `VAMP_PATH_32` environment variable instead of `VAMP_PATH`.)

source [from here](https://www.vamp-plugins.org/download.html?search=key&go=Go&platform=osx#:%7E:text=To%20install%20a%20plugin%20set,or%20personal%20Vamp%20plugin%20location.&text=On%20a%20Mac%3A,Audio%2FPlug%2DIns%2FVamp)